# Error with Slick Module when clearing cache during installation

Tags: docker, drupal, composer-php

Has anyone run into this before?

I am doing a local install of Drupal 8 with docker and composer.  I'm on a Windows machine using WSL.  When I clear the cache (drush cr), I get this error:

Service "slick.manager":  Parent definition "blazy.manager.base" does not exist.

Both Slick and Blazy modules and libraries are present.  When I try to go to the site it says "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please share more details, like your debugging attempts and the connection to [tag:composer-php]

Answer (score -1):

Just uninstall the slick module, load the site, install blazy, then enable the slick module again.  It's an "ordering" issue due to a new dependency.

See; https://www.drupal.org/project/slick/issues/2702241

It's a bit of a workaround but it should solve your problem.

If this isn't the issue, then please update your question with the output of;

```
drush pml --status=enabled
```

(Just for the two modules if you don't wish to copy everything here).

Comment: I actually tried that but got a different error.  I appreciate the effort.

Comment: All good- do you see them both when you use this;  drush pml --status=enabled

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer by editing it, instead of linking to external ressources

Comment: @NicoHaase Done - apologies, I should have read the guidelines better.

Comment: When I ran the "drush pml --status=enabled" command, I got the same message "Service "slick.manager": Parent definition "blazy.manager.base" does not exist.

Comment: When you uninstalled the modules previously, how did you do it?  Did you run; `drush pmu blazy slick -y` Make sure they are probably removed before adding them back.  Also make sure to `drush cr` too.